# Web lookup from konsole

Tags: kde, konsole

I somehow reinstalled Firefox snap (I have KDE Plasma). Since then, when I select a string inside konsole and then search with... I get a popup saying error code unknown 100, complaining it can't find that folder, because /snap/firefox/*numeric value has changed.
I tried renaming that folder but it always says resource busy, even if I kill firefox.